# Symfony2 Entity Form Type gets data

Tags: forms, symfony, types, get, entity

I have 2 entities: Audio and Destination

In Audio:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Destination", inversedBy="audio")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This field must be filled")
     * 
     */
    private $destination;
```

I created a Form Type name AddAudioType used to upload an audio to database

```
<?php

namespace HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Audio;

class AddAudioType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name','text')
            ->add('content','file')
            ->add('destination','entity',array('class'=>'HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination','property'=>'name'))
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class'=>"HearWeGo\\HearWeGoBundle\\Entity\\Audio"));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'add_audio';
    }
}
?>
```

In Controller

```
/**
     * @Route("/admin/add/audio",name="add_audio")
     */
    public function addAudioAction(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')){
            return  new Response('Please login');
        }

        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

        $audio=new Audio();
        $form=$this->createForm(new AddAudioType(),$audio,array(
            'method'=>'POST',
            'action'=>$this->generateUrl('add_audio')
        ));
        $form->add('submit','submit');
        if ($request->getMethod()=='POST')
        {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $destination=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination')
                    ->findByName($form->get('destination')->getData()->getName());
                $audio->setDestination($destination);
                $name=$_FILES['add_audio']['name']['content'];
                $tmp_name=$_FILES['add_audio']['tmp_name']['content'];
                if (isset($name))
                {
                    if (!empty($name))
                    {
                        $location=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bundles/hearwegohearwego/uploads/";
                        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$name);
                        $audio->setContent($location.$name);
                        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                        $em->persist($audio);
                        $em->flush();
                        return new Response('Audio '.$audio->getName().' has been created!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->render('@HearWeGoHearWeGo/manage/addAudio.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView()));
    }
```

In AddAudioType, I declared so that it gets all records from Destination entity table and allows user to choose one of them, then persist it to database

Now there's something another I have to handle: Because relationship between Audio and Destination is one-to-one, user is not allowed to choose a Destination which already appeared in Audio table. Now in AddAudioType, I don't want to get all records from Destination table, but only some that hasn't appeared in Audio table yet. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do in your form builder

```
->add('destination', 'entity', array(
    'class'=>'HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination',
    'property'=>'name'
));
```

you're saying that you want all of possible `Destination` entities

If you want to filter them, you have two possibilities

#### First one (recommended)

Write your own method to exclude already "associated" `Destinations` into `DestionationRepository`. If you don't know what is a repository or you don't know how to write one, please refer to this [document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes). Method implementation is left to you as an exercise (No, really, I don't know all entities so I cannot make any guess)

Once you've done this, you have to pass `DestinationRepository` to your form, as an option (**required** I suppose [see `setRequired()` method below]), so, something like this (I'll omit uninteresting code)

```
//AddAudioType
<?php
    [...]
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $destination_repo = $options['dr'];

        $builder->[...]
                ->add('destination','entity',array(
                    'class'=>'HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination',
                    'choices'=> $destination_repo->yourCustomRepoFunctionName(),
                    'property'=>'name'));
    }

    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'dr',
    ));
```

Now that you have setted all for your form, you need to pass `DestinationRepository` to your form. How do you that?
It's quite simple indeed

```
//In controller you're instatiating your form
[...]
public function addAudioAction()
{
    [...]
    $destination_repo = $this->getDoctrine()
                             ->getManager()
                             ->getRepository('HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination');

    $form=$this->createForm(new AddAudioType(), $audio, array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('add_audio'), 
            'dr' => $destination_repo,
    ));
}
```

It's going to work like a charm as long as you write a good "filter" method (ie.: you exlude with `NOT IN` clause all `Destinations` that got the key into other table)

---

#### Second one

You simply write your method into the form

```
//AddAudioType
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

<?php 
    [...]
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $destination_repo = $options['dr'];

        $builder->[...]
                ->add('destination','entity',array(
                    'class'=>'HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination',
                    'choices'=> function(EntityRepository $repository) use ($someParametersIfNeeded) { 
                                    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('d')
                                        ->[...];},
                    'property'=>'name'));
    }
```

In this second case, `createQueryBuilder` is also not implemented and left to you. One thing you need to remember: `choices` will need a query builder, so don't call `->getQuery()` and `->getResult()`

---

#### Why fist one?

- Custom function should always stay within repos. So you are writing some code into the place that has to be (see points below to know way)
- Because code, that way, is reusable (DRY principle)
- Because you can test code more easily

---

#### Custom repo function

```
public function findDestinationWithoutAudio() { 
    $query= "SELECT d 
             FROM HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination d 
             WHERE d NOT IN (SELECT IDENTITY(a.destination) 
                             FROM HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Audio a)"
    ; 
    
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($query)->getResult();
}
```

If you want to know why you should use `IDENTITY()` function and not foreign key directly: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions

Comment: I followed the first solution, I write the following method in DestinationRepository:

`public function findDestinationWithoutAudio()
    {
        $query='SELECT d FROM HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination d WHERE d NOT IN (SELECT a.destination FROM HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Audio a)';
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($query)->getResult();
    }`

I encountered new problem:
`Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`

In Audio entity, `$destination` is an instance of Destination type, so I can't  use `id` in query

Comment: @necroface: and ... ? (btw from a first look, I'm not sure about your return statement)

Comment: I edited the above comment, it concerns with createQuery

Comment: The error stuck right in the query. And I don't know how to write a proper query in this case

Comment: I have to dig out this old question to ask for one thing: If my customRepoFunction has some parameters, for example:

`public function findByAudioId($id)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT d FROM HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination d,HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Audio a WHERE d.id=IDENTITY (a.destination)')->getResult();
    }`

What will I put in
`'choices'=> $destination_repo->yourCustomRepoFunctionName()`

Could you please help me again

Comment: @necroface: please open a new question and I will take a look. Please provide as more details as possible.