# Symfony2 Entity Form Type gets data from another Entity

Tags: forms, symfony, get, repository, entity

I have 2 entities: Audio and Destination

In Audio:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Destination", inversedBy="audio")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This field must be filled")
     * 
     */
    private $destination;
```

I created a Form Type name EditAudioType used to edit an audio whose uploaded link is stored in database

```
<?php

namespace HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Audio;

class AudioAudioType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $destination_repo=$options['dr'];

        $builder
            ->add('name','text')
            ->add('audio','file')
            ->add('destination','entity',array(
                'class'=>'HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination',
                'choices'=>$destination_repo->findToReplaceAudio('id'),
                'property'=>'name'
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class'=>"HearWeGo\\HearWeGoBundle\\Entity\\Audio"));
        $resolver->setRequired(array('dr'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'edit_audio';
    }

}
```

I did as the similar answer in my old post:
[Symfony2 Entity Form Type gets data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512350/symfony2-entity-form-type-gets-data/)

But now I don't know what I will put in `choices` attribute of form, because this custom repo function has parameter, not like the old answer. In `DestinationRepository`:

```
    public function findByAudioId($id)
        {
            return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT d FROM HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination d,HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Audio a WHERE d.id=IDENTITY (a.destination)')->getResult();
        }

   public function findToReplaceAudio($id)
        {
            $result=$this->findDestinationWithoutAudio();
            $result[]=$this->findByAudioId($id);
            return $result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do something like :

```
<?php

namespace HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Audio;
use HearWeGo\HearWeGoBundle\Entity\Repository\AudioRepository;

class AudioAudioType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name','text')
            ->add('audio','file')
            ->add('destination','entity',array(
                'class'=>'HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Destination',
                'query_builder'=>function (AudioRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->findToReplaceAudioQueryBuilder('id');
                },
                'property' => 'name'
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class'=>"HearWeGo\\HearWeGoBundle\\Entity\\Audio"));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'edit_audio';
    }
}
```

Please have a look to the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

Comment: All of those repo functions are in `DestinationRepository`, not in `AudioRepository`. In `DestinationRepository`, I use `id` of `Audio` to find respectively relational `Destination` entity

Comment: After changing, it got:

`Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given`

Comment: Yes, you must create a repository method that return the `QueryBuilder` object, ie : do not call `->getQuery()->execute()`

Comment: I'm having problems because my function `findToReplaceAudio` in `DestinationRepository` gets results from 2 function: `findDestinationWithoutAudio` and `findByAudioId`
Now I'm struggling to write a proper query builder to fit

Comment: Hard to help you cause I do not know what you are trying to achive (the functional I mean), but have a look to the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects